# Filter items where child nodes has the same name

Tags: javascript, json, xml, xpath

I have a large json blob which I want to parse and filter baser on parameters in a form.
After some research I decided to try defiantjs, but I have been running into issues when using XPath as it flattens my tree.

My data looks like this:

```
<d:item d:mi="36">
    <name d:constr="String" d:mi="15">/Vip/myvip</name>
    <irules d:mi="23">
        <name d:constr="String" d:mi="22">abcde</name>
    </irules>
    <irules d:mi="25">
        <name d:constr="String" d:mi="24">fgh</name>
    </irules>
    <irules d:mi="27">
        <name d:constr="String" d:mi="26">ijkl</name>
    </irules>
</d:item>
<d:item d:mi="37">
    <name d:constr="String" d:mi="15">myitem2</name>
    <irules d:mi="23">
        <name d:constr="String" d:mi="22">mnop</name>
    </irules>
    <irules d:mi="25">
        <name d:constr="String" d:mi="24">qrst</name>
    </irules>
</d:item>
```

Is there any way to search for ie. a irules node that contains "fgh"? In the case below I would then get only the first item:

```
 <d:item d:mi="36">
    <name d:constr="String" d:mi="15">/Vip/myvip</name>
    <irules d:mi="23">
        <name d:constr="String" d:mi="22">abcde</name>
    </irules>
    <irules d:mi="25">
        <name d:constr="String" d:mi="24">fgh</name>
    </irules>
    <irules d:mi="27">
        <name d:constr="String" d:mi="26">ijkl</name>
    </irules>
```

I did fiddle around with queries but could only get a hit on the first irules node (?) but not the subsequent ones.

Bonus question:

Any other recommendations for parsing large abounts of json data with javascript (~12MB)?

/Patrik

Comment: Why XML?? Nobody uses that. Use JSON

Comment: **Bonus comment:** what have you tried yourself?

Comment: @patrikj do you need an path for getting the item node? which xpath did you try?

Comment: @Jonasw I am. But defiantjs is converting it to xml in order to be able to apply XPath to it

Comment: @1252748 So far Jsonpath, defiant, and plain javascript. I have also looked at json linq and json query but not tested them yet.

Comment: @eLRuLL Correct This is the closest I have come '//virtualserver[contains(./irules, "whatIwanttofind")]' (defiantjs starts the queries with //)

However it would only return objects where the top rule in the list contains "whatIwanttofind".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Correct This is the closest I have come '`//virtualserver[contains(./irules, "whatIwanttofind")]`' (defiantjs starts the queries with //) However it would only return objects where the top rule in the list contains "whatIwanttofind"*

That's because `contains()` function expect only one string as the first parameter. In case of `./irules` returning multiple elements, only the first will be evaluated. To avoid this problem, you can modify the XPath applying `contains()` check on individual `irules` element :

```
//virtualserver[irules[contains(., "whatIwanttofind")]]
```